# How can I play playing a mp3 sound with flask?

Tags: python, flask, html5-audio

I am trying different things to play a sound when 20 seconds pass on the web page and there is no action made. I have tried to use audio tag:

```html
<audio controls>
    <source src="bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio src="bell.mp3" controls></audio>

<audio >
    <source src="bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It just display but does nothing, I am not sure how to play the sound and where to place the mp3 sound. I have it under templates and in the project file. Do I need to write some lines in `app.py` file?

Please suggest ...

Comment: I am assuming that the code you just showed is in the html template of the flask app.
To serve those files you will also need to serve them from the correct [static file of your flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/) app.
So in the folder `flask/static` you need to put the bell.mp3 file.
And in the `base.html` you add `<source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bell.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg">`

Comment: @Andi Domi it used to display the volume and the bar, i wrote your code but nothing happened on the page, if you mean by base.html is the html file i'm trying to make the sound coming from.

Comment: @Andi Domi got it now, you were missing <audio> tag. but how do i make it play if there is no action happens after period of time? lets say 20 sec

Comment: yes, i thought that was implied, and i just posted the lines which had to be modified. Does it work now?

Comment: @Andi Domi yes but i want to play the sound only if there is no action on the page happened after 20 sec.

Comment: Can you define what an action is? Mouse movement? Clicking a button?

Comment: @Andi Domi i have a timer for 20 sec if the user didn't answer the question posted it will display a window saying your time is up. i want to add a sound to that window.confirm. the sound should play if the user didn't choose from radio button. i have onload="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);" in the body

Comment: In that case you can completely run this from just javascript. You just need to add this to your js file 
`var audio = new Audio('bell.mp3');`
`audio.play();` 
in the `myFunction`. When this function will be called the audio will play

Comment: @Andi Domi it didn't work and i feel i'm around the solution. `function myFunction() {
var audio = new Audio('bell.mp3');
 audio.play();
 if (window.confirm('Your time is up!'))
{
window.location.href="/";
};
}`

Comment: can you try something like `function myFunction() {
    if (window.confirm('Your time is up!')) { 
                var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3');
    audio.play(); 
    };
}
`

Comment: @Andi Domi this did not work too because there is no action attached to window.confirm and the sound

Comment: that is for you to figure out, i cannot know what action you intend to be put there without having to look at your entire code..